# Searching partial names with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use `Get-ADComputer` in Powershell to search using variables when I know part of the computer name.

If I only use a string with quotes, it works great:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "*mputername*"} | Select Name`

If I create a string variable and THEN do the same search using the variable, it doesn't return anything.  I think it has something to do with how the variable is being expanded next to the wildcard asterisks, but I'm stumped.

`Set-Variable -Name 'partialName' -Value 'mputername'`

`Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "*$partialName*"} | Select Name`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `$nameFilter = "*mputername*"; Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $nameFilter}` should work.

Comment: While the ADCmdlets can technically take scriptblocks as filters, it's generally better to use strings for them: `Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '$namefilter'"`.

Comment: To add to the two helpful  comments: the linked duplicate explains solution options and also why using script blocks (`{ ... }`) is best avoided for conceptual reasons.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @puterguy01.